# htaccess RewriteRule only root page proxy to another page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to show on home page (root page) content of another page.
The easiest way is RewriteRule proxy, I think.

If I need to show page /abc/ at uri /test/ next rule works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/$
RewriteRule ^test/$ /abc/ [P]
```

If I need redirect from home page to /abc/ next rule works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /abc/ [R,L]
```

But if I need proxy from home page to page /abc/ next variant doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /abc/ [P]
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare the rewriteBase first, then a little modification

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^/$" "/abc/" [P]
```

Ensure you have mod_proxy enabled, even it should be per your description.
This according to Apache Documentations: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for answer.

mod_rewrite is enabled, I write code in condition: <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>.

I added code "RewriteBase /", but it still not working.

```RewriteRule "^/$" "/abc/" [P]``` - doesnt work.
```RewriteRule "^$" "/abc/" [R,L]``` - redirect works.
```RewriteRule "^/$" "/abc/" [R,L]``` - redirect with slash doesnt work.

I stil have no ideas.

Comment: What is the apache versions you use?
Have you tried adding the "cond", like
`RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule "^/$" "/abc/" [P]`